# HTTP request inside override GrabBegin not calling

Tags: oculusquest

I override `GrabBegin` function and try to make a Post request whenever user grab an object. But it looks like the Request was never called. No error or warning issue from the condole. I also tried to print to console by using `Debug.Log("Grab Begin")` but it was never printed to the console. I am not sure what I am missing. I was still able to grab an object through the VR

```
public class AromaShooterGrabbable : OVRGrabbable
{
    override public void GrabBegin(OVRGrabber hand, Collider grabPoint) {
        base.GrabBegin(hand, grabPoint);

        RestClient.Post<AromaShooterResponse>(url, new Post {
            duration = 3000,
            channel = 1,
            intensity = 100
        }).Then(response => {
            Debug.Log(response.status);
        }).Catch(error => {
            Debug.Log(error.Message);
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question.

In `AndroidManifest.OVRSubmission.xml` add:

```
<manifest>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <application
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@network_sec_config"
  >
</manifest>
```

In `network_sec_config.xml` add:

```
<domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
  <domain includeSubdomains="true">*</domain>
</domain-config>
<base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true"></base-config>
```